# How to Transpose a Mobily-blocks Jquery Effects to Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I see this jquery [effects][1] and i'm trying to make the same with Raphael.

Is this possible to become the same effect but instead of PNG or JPEG, with SVG(Raphael)?

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Are you asking for a solution using a single Raphael paper or do you mean to replace the various images in the effect with several Raphael objects?

Comment: I mean replace various images with several Raphael objects!! :D but i found now how to do it! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY Solution**

I just but my svg between li and modify the mobily-block to use it! and voila!

```
<li id="alto" ...>
<svg ...>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would be a problem, just use them as image and you are done...

Comment: Not really!! this didnt work for me! look my edit to see how i solve it!! Thank u anyway for your idea!!